# JQuery Select all divs after a certain row (divs are in random order, positioned absolute)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a grid of equal size absolute positioned randomly arranged divs and currently they have classes using the structure `columnX` and `rowY`. Where X and Y are variables corresponding to the div position.

So a div in the fourth column and the first row will have these two classes `column4` and `row1` as attributes values to class. I can change anything about the div structure as part of the solution.

[image]

```
<div id="container">
<div id="div3-2" class="column3 row2"></div><div id="div1-1" class="column1 row1"></div>
<div id="div2-3" class="column2 row3"></div><div id="div1-2" class="column1 row2"></div>
<div id="div2-1" class="column2 row1"></div><div id="div2-2" class="column2 row2"></div>
<div id="div3-1" class="column3 row1"></div><div id="div1-3" class="column1 row3"></div>
<div id="div1-2" class="column1 row2"></div><div id="div3-3" class="column3 row3"></div>
</div>
```

I want to select every div that is in a row after row 1. There are many divs and I don't want a slow process. Is there a more straightforward and efficient way, besides having to select every existing div and then going through and dissecting the class attributes for the numeric values bigger than 1?

Please note because of the random absolute positioning of the divs `.nextAll()` which would have been very convenient wont work.

**Updated:** Please see the best answer I currently have [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gr30ganj/17/). I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: It might be easier to use normally-positioned divs than solve this problem.  Is this a 2048 board?

Comment: Yes @James, ideally no one wants to use `absolute` but the grid interface is of a map so the absolute positioning in this case is a must due to how new tiles are added when someone scrolls outside the existing margins.

Comment: @j08691 Added code

Comment: You have no CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gr30ganj/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set row and column data attributes with unary-encoded numbers (eg 3 is 111, 7 is 1111111) you can select elements with attributes greater than those by using the "starts with" `^=` operator.

```js
// example, select all divs after row 2 column 2
// so two selectors, one selects divs on row 2 after column 2, the other selects all divs in rows 3, 4, etc  They are or'd together

function selectAfter(row, col) {
  var selector;
  if (row > 0 && col > 0) {
    var r = Array(row + 1).join("1");
    var c = Array(col + 1).join("1");
  
    selector = "#container div[data-row='" + r + "'][data-column^='" + c + "1'], #container div[data-row^='" + r + "1']";
  } else {
    selector = "#container div";
  }
  
  // from here down can be replaced with
  // $(selector).addClass("selected");
  // if using jquery
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

  for (var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].className += " selected";
  }
}

selectAfter(2, 2);
```

```css
#container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

#container div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;  
}
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
.column2 { left: 50px; }
.column3 { left: 100px; }
.row2 { top: 50px; }
.row3 { top: 100px; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="column3 row2" data-row="11" data-column="111"></div><div class="column1 row1" data-row="1" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="column2 row3" data-row="111" data-column="11"></div><div class="column1 row2" data-row="11" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="column2 row1" data-row="1" data-column="11"></div><div class="column2 row2" data-row="11" data-column="11"></div>
<div class="column3 row1" data-row="1" data-column="111"></div><div class="column1 row3" data-row="111" data-column="1"></div>
<div class="column3 row3" data-row="111" data-column="111"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you look at this solution at this url I just put here, can you tell me which one you believe would be the most appropriate https://jsfiddle.net/gr30ganj/4/

Comment: Am i right to think your solution involves less operations so should be less intensive?

Comment: Just to update I ran a timer against both codes and I was surprised to find out that my version ran much faster, please see updated: https://jsfiddle.net/gr30ganj/16/

Comment: If we're all of a sudden using jQuery then here is my change: https://jsfiddle.net/gr30ganj/18/

Comment: Its the first word in the title. Thanks tho your solution is indeed faster with jQuery.

Comment: Lol I don't know why I didn't see that.  Anyway hope that solves it for you.